# Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_XmlRpc_Value::getGenerator() magento

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, magento

I was upgrading magento when something went wrong and now when I try to login to admin, I am unable to log in to back end admin of magento and I get the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_XmlRpc_Value::getGenerator() in /home/boutique/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Request.php on line 413
```

and the code on respective lines is

```
/**
     * Create XML request
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function saveXml()
    {
        $args   = $this->_getXmlRpcParams();
        $method = $this->getMethod();

        $generator = Zend_XmlRpc_Value::getGenerator();
        $generator->openElement('methodCall')
                  ->openElement('methodName', $method)
                  ->closeElement('methodName');
```

I cant understand why this issue is happening, I tried replacing request.php and response.php files from fresh download of magento..

can body help me? why this eror is popping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something about your installation of PHP and Magento that's broken — for some reason the `Zend_XmlRpc_Value` object that's instantiated doesn't contain a `getGenerator` method.  The class for this object is normally defined in

```
lib/Zend/XmlRpc/Value.php
```

However, it's possible there may be a class override in place at

```
app/code/core/Zend/XmlRpc/Value.php
app/code/community/Zend/XmlRpc/Value.php
app/code/local/Zend/XmlRpc/Value.php
```

It's also possible your system may have another version of the zend framework installed somewhere in the PHP include path.

Comment: what do you suggest? should I go for upgrade again? as I am getting new error now? I was using downloader method and something went wrong

Comment: I'd suggest rolling up your sleeves and using this as a learning experience.

Comment: awesome comments ,,, I am on it, thanks for the guideline bro